# Examples of complex designs

Tags: oop, design-patterns, software-design

I am interested now in design patterns and system design, and it seems that the examples are simple and it misses how things are put together in a real complex system.

Do you know when I can find examples of complex designs that use the basics principles?

Comment: You probably wouldn't be able to recognize designs in complex systems, which is why they're complex and not many examples exist.

Comment: Have you looked at any well-known, well-maintained open-source libraries (such as Spring, if you're familiar with Java)?  You should be able to find good real-word examples by going through their code.

Answer (score 0):

I understood you mean real world system, not real complex system.
Would you be more specific in which language do you want to implement it? For example I work with Delphi/ObjectPascal and I am studying  design patterns and system design as you. Most part of good examples I found looking for OOP Interface Delphi. As you know, Interface looks like abstract classes. I also heard about Independency Injections, and bought a book of Nick Hodges: Independency Injections in Delphi.

http://www.nickhodges.com/page/Dependency-Injection-Series.aspx

He also suggests Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seeman
[https://www.amazon.com/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_img_0/136-1024374-7962003?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=Q6B1JT81ZE5MPRQ83K11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501)
And I found "`**Dependency Injection: With Examples in Java, Ruby, and C#`**-`Design Patterns using Spring and Guice`" by Dhanji R. Prasanna.

I'm surprised because a long time a didn't found good books of OOP.
Actually, have many examples in internet, if you look from perspective of specific language or tool.
I hope had contributed for the discussion. Good Look.